# Factory for object init and configuration

Tags: java

I want to extract the creation of different objects in a factory class for the reason of reusability. The problem is that within the current code the objects are configured also for the specific problem. Now I want to reuse only the creation of the objects within another code place.

```
 if (FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.TEXTFIELD == type)
            {
                TextField textField = new TextField(caption);
                textField.setNullRepresentation("");
                bind(textField, propertyId);
                field = textField;
                if (field.getValue() == null && isNestedProperty)
                {
                    ObjectProperty property = new ObjectProperty("", String.class);
                    textField.setPropertyDataSource(property);
                }
            }
            else if (FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.SEARCHFIELD == type)
            {
                SearchBox searchField = new SearchBox(caption);
                bind(searchField, propertyId);
                field = searchField;
            }
            else if (FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.DATEFIELD == type)
            {
                DateField dateField = new DateField();
                dateField.setCaption(caption);
                dateField.setDateFormat(UilibI18N.dateFormat.getText());
                dateField.setResolution(Resolution.DAY);
                bind(dateField, propertyId);
```

I want to reuse only the creation of the objects at another code place too, can anybody give me a hint what's the right way to extract the creation logic?

Comment: Your code excerpt is incomplete. To get better answers, and for your own benefit it would be nice to include your whole method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bruno. The other logic in the method is the same, depending on a FieldType, a object is created an initalized. Now I need just the creation logic of an object also at another code place (depending also on a FieldType) ... my questions is now: what is the nicest way to do this? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I find the right word in you question - 'extract'.

## Code style

**Logic section**

Use blank lines to separate your code into logical sections

Instead of:

```
DateField dateField = new DateField();
dateField.setCaption(caption);
dateField.setDateFormat(UilibI18N.dateFormat.getText());
dateField.setResolution(Resolution.DAY);
bind(dateField, propertyId);
```

You can use:

```
// creation logic part
DateField dateField = new DateField();

// setting the field's properties logic part
dateField.setCaption(caption);
dateField.setDateFormat(UilibI18N.dateFormat.getText());
dateField.setResolution(Resolution.DAY);

// bind operation logic part
bind(dateField, propertyId);
```

## Design issue

I read your code very carefully and I've found that you use 2 variables in all your 3 if/else conditions.

They are **caption** and **propertyID**.

Assume that these 2 properties will be an input of some method which we'll call (I don't know the context, that's why I'll use the random name) **makeOperationWithField**

```
public void makeOperationWithField(int propertyID, String caption) {
 // some code
}
```

I'll move deeply and remove this big if/else if statements.

**Replace conditional with polymorphism**.

Lets do it step by step.

*Step1*

Create an abstract class that will create objects depending on field's type.

```
abstract class FieldConfigurationType {
  static final int TEXTFIELD = FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.TEXTFIELD;
  static final int SEARCHFIELD = FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.SEARCHFIELD;
  static final int DATEFIELD = FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.DATEFIELD;

  abstract void makeOperationWithField(int propertyID, String caption);

  public static FieldConfigurationType newType(int code) {
    switch (code) {
      case TEXTFIELD:
        return new TextFieldConfiguration();
      case SEARCHFIELD:
        return new SearchFieldConfiguration();
      case DATEFIELD:
        return new DateFieldConfiguration();
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect Field Type");
    }
  }
}
```

Now, we can use the simple construction:

```
FieldConfigurationType fieldType = FieldConfigurationType.newType(type);
fieldType.makeOperationWithField(propertyID, caption);
```

*Step 2*

Add separate implementation for each field type.

```
public class TextFieldConfiguration extends FieldConfigurationType {
  @Override public void makeOperationWithField(int propertyID, String caption) {
    TextField textField = new TextField(caption);
    textField.setNullRepresentation("");

    bind(textField, propertyId);

    field = textField;

    if (field.getValue() == null && isNestedProperty) {
      ObjectProperty property = new ObjectProperty("", String.class);
        textField.setPropertyDataSource(property);
    }
  }
}

public class SearchFieldConfiguration extends FieldConfigurationType {
  @Override public void makeOperationWithField(int propertyID, String caption) {
    SearchBox searchField = new SearchBox(caption);
    bind(searchField, propertyId);

    field = searchField;
  }
}

public class DateFieldConfiguration extends FieldConfigurationType {
  @Override public void makeOperationWithField(int propertyID, String caption) {
    DateField dateField = new DateField();

    dateField.setCaption(caption);
    dateField.setDateFormat(UilibI18N.dateFormat.getText());
    dateField.setResolution(Resolution.DAY);

    bind(dateField, propertyId);
  }
}
```

If you need to add a new field type, all you need to do is just add new subclass without rewriting the existing code. [Open/Closed Principle](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily separate creation from configuration.

```
    void buildObject() {
    GenericField field;
    switch (type) {
    case FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.TEXTFIELD:
        TextField textField = new TextField(caption);
        field = textField;
        break;
    case FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.SEARCHFIELD:
        SearchBox searchField = new SearchBox(caption);
        field = searchField;
        break;
    case FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.DATEFIELD:
        DateField dateField = new DateField();
        field = dateField;
        break;

    }
    switch (type) {
        case FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.TEXTFIELD:
            TextField textField = (TextField) field;
            textField.setNullRepresentation("");
            if (field.getValue() == null && isNestedProperty) {
                ObjectProperty property = new ObjectProperty("", String.class);
                textField.setPropertyDataSource(property);
            }
            break;
        case FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.SEARCHFIELD:
            break;
        case FieldConfiguration.FIELD_TYPE.DATEFIELD:
            DateField dateField = (TextField) field;
            dateField.setCaption(caption);
            dateField.setDateFormat(UilibI18N.dateFormat.getText());
            dateField.setResolution(Resolution.DAY);
            break;

    }
    bind(dateField, propertyId);
```